# gluTessCallback complaints about missing _stdcall for callback pointer

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a chunck of code which uses GLU tessellator. Some of the methods are passed callbacks.It usually looks like that:

```
static void vertexCallback(void* vertexData, void* data)
{

}
```

Them passing the callback into the gluTessCallback method:

```
gluTessCallback(tess, GLU_TESS_VERTEX_DATA,
                         reinterpret_cast<GLvoid (*)()>(vertexCallback));
```

This code compiled for me on one machine (Win7 64bit ,VisualStudio2012 VC110 compiler 64bit project).

But when I setup the same project on another machine which is also Win7 64bit, VS2012, VC110 ,but **32bit** project I am getting the compiler spitting this:

> Error 4   error C2664: 'gluTessCallback' : cannot convert parameter 3
>   from 'GLvoid (__cdecl *)(void)' to 'void (__stdcall *)(void)'

Why does this happen?

Comment: You are trying to hammer a square peg into a round hole.  No amount of smashing, like you tried with that horrible cast, is going to turn your callback function into a one that uses the __stdcall calling convention.  Remove the cast, declare the function properly.

Comment: As Hans is saying, you have to define your callback with __cdecl modifier. The reason it worked on 64 bit, is there is only one type of calling conventions, while on x86, there are several.

Comment: All right!That's the info I have been missing. Btw, that piece of code comes from Apple's WebCore lib.Probably on GCC or LLVM it does work that way.But why should I define with __cdecl if it actually asks for __stdcall?